# Getting Version History and What Field has Changed

Tags: 2007, javascript, spservices

I am using the GetVersionCollection to get the history information from my list.  This seems to be working fine; however, what I need to do is get the version history of the individual item which has been changed in the SharePoint list.  From what I can understand on the web service call, it goes by individual list item and the version of that item.  Is there a way to get the information of the list item which has been changed?  I need this to work like the View History in SharePoint but what I am trying to do is view all version changed for all items based on date instead of one at a time.  Here is what I have done so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

var proID = new Array();
var proTitle = new Array();
var proModified = new Array();
var proHistory = new Array();
var i = 0;

$().SPServices({
   operation: "GetListItems",
   async: false,
   listName: "NewProjects",
   webURL: "http://devchrisl01/test",
   //CAMLQuery: '<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ProjectOpen" /><Value Type="Boolean">1</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Title" Ascending="True" /></OrderBy></Query>',
   CAMLViewFields: '<ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Title" /><FieldRef Name="ID" /><FieldRef Name="Modified" /><FieldRef Name="History" /></ViewFields>',

   completefunc: function(xdata, status) 
   {

            //alert(xdata.responseXML.xml);
        $(xdata.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {


            var xitem = $(this);
            var ID = xitem.attr('ows_ID');
            var Title = xitem.attr('ows_Title');
            var Modified = xitem.attr('ows_Modified');
            var History = xitem.attr('ows_History');

           //alert(ID);
            proID[i] = ID;
            proTitle[i] = Title;
            proModified[i] = Modified;
            proHistory[i] = History;
            i++;

            });

   }

});





for (i=0; i < proID.length; i++){

$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetVersionCollection",
      async: false,
      webURL: "http://devchrisl01/test",
      strlistID: "NewProjects",
      strlistItemID: proID[i].toString(),
      strFieldName: "History",
      completefunc: function (xdata, Status) {


        $(xdata.responseText).find("Version").each(function() {

       //alert(xdata.responseXML.xml);

            var xitem = $(this);
            var ID = xitem.attr('ID');
            var Title = xitem.attr('Title');
            var Modified = xitem.attr('Modified');
            var History = xitem.attr('History');


                //var data = "<tr><td>" + proID[i].toString() + "</td><td>" + proModified[i].toString() + "</td><td>" + proTitle[i].toString() + "</td></tr>";
                var data = "<tr><td>" + proID[i] + "</td><td>" + Modified + "</td><td>" + History + "</td><td>" + proTitle[i] + "</td></tr>";

                $('#tester').append(data);


        });  

      }

   });

  }

});


</script>

</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<table id="tester" cellpadding="5px"><th>Project Number</th><th>Modified</th><th>History</th><th>Project Name</th></table>  
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I am getting the information back for each list item doing it this way, the only thing missing is the information of the list item which has been changed.  I only want the list items to show if the item has been changed.  Doing it this way, I am getting everything back.  I hope I am being clear on what I am trying to do.  Thanks for the Views!!

Comment: Have you tried using search to pre-filter items by list URL and date before calling the webservice for specific items?

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of which Items has changed since a certain time you can use [Lists.GetListItemChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitemchanges%28v=office.12%29.aspx), but to get the individual changes you have to loop through the Version History and build it up.

Comment: I am not going to be able to put a time into the code.  This would work, but my big caveot is not being able to hard code a date.  Thank you for the response :)